# Can't install the PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I try to install the phpspreadysheet but these error occurs

```
Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.


  [RuntimeException]
  No composer.json present in the current directory (./composer.json), this may   
  be the cause of the following exception.
                                                                                   


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet has requirements incompatible with your PHP v   
  ersion, PHP extensions and Composer version:                                     
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.22.0 requires ext-fileinfo * but it is not pres   
  ent.                                                                             
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.22.0 requires ext-gd * but it is not present.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am stuck with these errors for two days and could not find the solution.
Thank you

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. I would suggest making sure you're running the command in the correct folder. Is there more to the error than you have shown here? What code are you running when getting this error?

Comment: The error message says you need two PHP extensions that aren't present. You don't even mention that, so it's unclear whether they are installed but Composer won't recognise them or you're just asking how to install PHP extensions. For what it's worth, Composer is a command-line tool so it'll often use a different php.ini file that your web server.

Comment: I found the solution. I just uncomment the fileinfo and gd on php.ini. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

open php.ini, search and uncomment following

1. extension=gd
2. extension=fileinfo

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, you have to do the following:

1. located the file `c:/xampp/php/php`
2. open the file
3. search for `fileinfo` and `gd`
4. if your see `;extension=fileinfo`
   `;extension=gd`
5. Remove the semicolon so it will be like this:
   `extension=fileinfo`
   `extension=gd`
6. Close the file and run the package again

Answer (score 3):

Running these three commands worked for me, in my case:

```
composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
composer require "ext-fileinfo:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in visual studio and **click ctr+shift+**` to open terminal or open cmd and to your project directory

and paste below code

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd
```

Above syntax worked form me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same error
First, check which php.ini file you are working with
with command:
PHP -ini
That's happened to me because I have both Xampp and Wamp on my machine
and even fix extensions won't make it work

and to add a gd extension do these steps:

Open Wamp on the taskbar and then open the PHP version you are using then edit extensions
search for fileinfo and gd
if your see ;extension=fileinfo ;extension=gd
Remove the semicolon so it will be like this: extension=fileinfo extension=gd
Close the file and re-run the Wampp

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand what version of PHP the composer is running on; you can find out by entering the command into the console:

```
php -v
```

After that, open the folder of this version of PHP and look for the php.ini file, and uncomment the lines that are asked in the error, these are:

```
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd
extension=zip
```

And voila, everything works! In a new way, we run the composer command to load the library.